# Professional way to show a plot of a function of three variables

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, function-construction

I want to make a  Plot of the following function of 3 variables (`r1, r2,\[Theta]`):

```
f=(2 E^(r2 + (E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
  2 (1 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))) - (
  E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
  2 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))))/(Sqrt[E^(
 2 r2)/(1 + 
  E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))] (2 + 
   E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1])))
```

for several values of `x0`. For this, I chose the command `SliceContourPlot3D[]` in order to make a slice plot of the previous function in the region: `{r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}`; then, for `x0=0` I use

```
Table[SliceContourPlot3D[(
   2 E^(r2 + (E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
     2 (1 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))) - (
     E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
     2 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))))/(
   Sqrt[E^(2 r2)/(
    1 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))] (2 + 
      E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))) /. {x0 -> 0},
   sl, {r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  Contours -> {0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  Ticks -> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, Pi, 2 Pi}}, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]], {sl, {"CenterCutBox", 
   "BackPlanes"}}]
```

producing the following result:

[image]

For `x0=1.75` I use:

```
Table[SliceContourPlot3D[(
   2 E^(r2 + (E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
     2 (1 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))) - (
     E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
     2 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))))/(
   Sqrt[E^(2 r2)/(
    1 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))] (2 + 
      E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))) /. {x0 -> 
     1.75}, sl, {r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  Contours -> {0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
  Ticks -> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, Pi, 2 Pi}}, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]], {sl, {"CenterCutBox", 
   "BackPlanes"}}]
```

producing:
[image]
For `x0=3.5` I use:

```
 Table[SliceContourPlot3D[(
       2 E^(r2 + (E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
         2 (1 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))) - (
         E^(2 r2) x0^2)/(
         2 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))))/(
       Sqrt[E^(2 r2)/(
        1 + E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))] (2 + 
          E^(2 r2) (Cosh[2 r1] - Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[2 r1]))) /. {x0 -> 
         3.5}, sl, {r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotLegends -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
      ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
      Contours -> {0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
      Ticks -> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, Pi, 2 Pi}}, 
      BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black], 
      ImageSize -> Medium, 
      TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14]], {sl, {"CenterCutBox", 
       "BackPlanes"}}]
```

producing:
[image]

Then, as can be verified from the previous pictures, the value of the function `f` is decreasing in the established region `{r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}`. **My objective is to display this decreasing effect in the ContourPlots of the function** `f`.

Then, my question is:

**Can someone give me another suggestion to display professionally the decreasing effect of the function `f` in a plot?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 3D static plots are, at best, dubiously interpreted due to perspective limitations. Now adding another dimension and throwing color/opacity in the mix makes it even more fragile. A possible workaround would be to use animation but that would change the nature of the question. Thus this question can attract multiple opinionated and partially (un)related answers; but that is my opinion only.

Comment: You can [plot the average value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4deKJ.png) of $f$ inside your box? `fmean[x00_?NumericQ] := (2*2*2 Pi)^(-1) NIntegrate[f /. x0 -> x00, {r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]; Plot[fmean[x0], {x0, 0, 4}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]`

Comment: What is the point to do such a thing when it is mathematically evident that the function is decreasing for `x0>0` since it can be rewritten as `c1 E^(-(x0^2/c2))` for some positive constants `c1` and `c2` that are dependent on `r1`, `r2` and `θ`? Math speaks more clear than any plot.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to answering this question is to determine whether `f` actually is insensitive to increasing `x0` from1.75 to 3.5.  So, do a direct numerical comparison.

```
ContourPlot3D[(f /. {x0 -> 3.5}) - (f /. {x0 -> 1.75}), {r1, -1, 1}, {r2, -1, 1}, 
    {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 25, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
     AxesLabel -> {r1, r2, \[Theta]}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Given that the range of `f` is approximately {0, 1}, the differences in `f` between the two `x0` values are not small.  They only appear to be in the plots in the question, because the larger values of `f` change less than the smaller values as `x0` is increased and the larger values tend to catch the eye more than the smaller values.